# Eclipse unable to get info on the interpreter in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8. Running Eclipse 4.2.2 with Pydev installed.

I have a Django project that I run in a virtual environment for obvious reasons (libraries versioning etc.)

When I attempt to point Eclipse to the interpreter 'python2.7' in the bin folder of the virtual environment, Eclipse spits out the error that it has failed to get info on the interpreter. Either it's unsupported (it is 2.7 so we're fine there) or it's an invalid interpreter (but I'm pointing to the alias).

[image: folders]
[image: eclipse error]

Any ideas what could be causing this, or steps to fix it?

Comment: CMD + , -> check "interpreter - python" under PyDev section... maybe you have to add something under "libraries" (I added all the stuff in my virtualenv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up resetting my virtual environment and it fixed the problem. All I needed to do was go up to the directory the virtual environment was in and type:

```
virtualenv .
```

Worked like a charm.

If you need it, you can go through the full steps to set up a virtual environment here: 
http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/