# Linking Conda's virtual environment to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, conda

i want to use conda's virtual environment for running my python scripts but anyway i will be using eclipse only to write the scripts.. is there a away that i can link eclipse to the virtual environment? so when i run scripts on eclipse , it will actually run in the virtual environment i have already created??

a question similar to my concern was found here

[Eclipse unable to get info on the interpreter in virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683329/eclipse-unable-to-get-info-on-the-interpreter-in-virtual-environment)

but i did not understand the answer given to this one Appreciate any help on this. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

In anaconda directories there is envs directory with subdirectories for each environment you created. The structure ( libs ...) are similar like directly in anaconda directory.

In PyDev: Window-> Preferences : PyDev->Interpreters->Python interpreter then clik "Browse for python/pypy exe" - the locate interpreter in bin directory of environment for example:

```
 <ANACONDA_DIR>/envs/<ENV_NAME/bin/python
```

then "Apply" and (after few minutes of configuration) right now your interpreter is available at Debug Configurations.
By the way at Preferences-> PyDev->Interpreters->Python (window as above) you can see at "Packages" tab the list of your packages and their version

I found that environments are directories: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html#list-all-environments