# Problems with importing netcdf4 and xarray when debugging - in eclipse + pydev on windows

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have been a staunch user of Eclipse on Windows - mostly for developing Python code. Lately, I needed to do something with the packages xarray and netcdf4. I first used an old version of Eclipse, but when I encountered problems I installed the latest LiClipse - version 8.2.0 (64 bits) on my Windows 10 machine. I use Miniconda 3 py37_4.9.2 (64 bits) with Anaconda Navigator 2.1.2 to manage my Python environments. I wrote a script of only a few lines. When I tried to import package netcdf4, I got an import error immediately that one of the netcdf4 DLLs could not be found after pressing the debug button. When I tried working without direct involvement of netcdf4 but only with xarray, I also got an import error that my packages were not configured correctly. When I started the script - outside Eclipse - from the command-line, there was no problem at all. BTW, I tried running with different Python versions: 3.6, 3.8 and 3.9 but that made no difference. I suspect that Pydev does not work together well with the packages netcdf4 and xarray. Has anybody else experienced similar problems?

Comment: netCDF and xarray are relatively high-level libraries compared to what you're wrestling with. It's far more likely (IMO) that you're running into trouble connecting Eclipse/PyDev to your conda library, or to low-level C or Fortran binaries managed by conda and required by xarray/netcdf. I'd recommend really carefully checking your import paths with `where` and `import library; library.__file__` to make sure you don't have conflicting versions being mashed together by PyDev.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking Conda's virtual environment to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123910/linking-condas-virtual-environment-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like some environment variable isn't properly set when running from PyDev...

Do you have the flag to load conda environment variables set in the interpreter configuration?

i.e.:

[image]

Note: if it runs in the command line you can compare the values you have in `os.environ` from one to the other to find what may be different (in general just making sure that the conda environment variables are loaded should do the trick, but if it doesn't comparing those and setting what's needed in the `Environment` tab may help).